# Docker php version is incorrect with docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'am new in docker. I set php container with php version 7.2 but phpinfo() shows php version 7.0. What I'am doing wrong ?

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env_file:
            - ./mysql.env
        volumes:
            - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        build: ./fitter
        container_name: web
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./fitter:/var/www
            - ./nginx-site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
            - ./storage/app:/var/www/storage/app
            - ./storage/logs:/var/www/storage/logss
        links:
            - php
    php:
        image: php:7.2-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./fitter:/var/www
```

And nginx-site.conf

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass fitter_docker_php_1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Command like  "docker exec web php -v" shows "PHP 7.0.15 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 21:25:43) ( NTS )"

Comment: docker compose down, delete all containers, do another build, and try again

Comment: and if you execute php -v on your php container? I tried with juste a container php and I have 7.2.6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you run a set of services with docker-compose it will create a docker network and start all the services inside that network, that means that all your containers inside that network can communicate with each other and you can use the name you defined for each service as a DNS record.

Change this:

> fastcgi_pass fitter_docker_php_1:9000;

To

> fastcgi_pass php:9000;

Also if you changed the php image version you have to pull the new image before restarting your compose stack, as the container will need to be recreated with the new image.

And you can remove the "links" from your docker compose as its not necessary in this case and also a legacy feature, you can read more about that here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: I've changed fastcgi_pass To
fastcgi_pass php:9000;

and phpinfo() still shows PHP Version 7.0.15

Comment: After pull new php image, I only see "Welcome to nginx!" page. It not read my index.php file. I opened ssh connection with web container and in /etc/ directory missing any php folders

Comment: Are you sure the php container is using the 7.2 image? Recreate all just in case. docker-compose down && docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

down your Docker and remove images using

```
docker rmi $(docker image ls -aq)
```

then rebuild them

```
docker-compose up --build
```

there you go, new container building based on new images